# A tree shaped network using d3

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to d3, and I'm trying to figure out how to create a network that looks like a tree, but unlike a tree it can have nodes that loop back to a parent node.
The image below shows a simple example of such network.

[image]

As you can see, each generation is in a different row, like a tree, but one node connects back to a parent node.

Comment: Have you started your project? If so, please post code.

Comment: @Incodeveritas - I initially did it as a tree layout, and then I realized a tree layout in d3 cannot loop back, so I don't think my code will be helpful

Comment: Your best bet is probably to run a tree layout without the looping back links, then add those. Unless you have a lot of links that loop back, this should work reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Lars Kotthoff's suggestion, I created a regular d3 tree, and then added all the links that loop back to parent nodes. It seems that d3 trees work without any problems when links are added in this way.